# Accessing nested collections and document in Firebase (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

If you cannot understand the title I am very sorry. I am new to NoSQL don't know how to address this problem.

i am having a nested collection inside my firebase database.
[first collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJa20.png)

[clicking on '145'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRKzo.png)

[clicking on 'location'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60yhX.png)

in the chargepoints method I have hardcoded (.doc('WPHW9669')) instead of that I have to loop through the 145 collection and get the document first. after that I have to go inside that looped document to access the 'location' collection.

this is the code which needs to be modified:

```
  chargePoints() {
    _db
        .collection('bus')
        .doc('Routes')
        .collection('145')
        .doc('WPHW9669') // this the place where the first iteration have to occur
        .collection('location')
        .orderBy('updatedTime', descending: true)
        .limit(1)
        .get()
        .then((docs) {
      if (docs.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < docs.docs.length; i++) {
          LatLng position = LatLng(
              docs.docs[i].data()['position']['geopoint'].latitude,
              docs.docs[i].data()['position']['geopoint'].longitude);
          print(docs.docs[i].data()['position']['geopoint'].latitude);
          initMarker(position, docs.docs[i].id);
          // notifyListeners();
          // initMarker(docs.docs[i].data(), docs.docs[i].id);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: What's your question?  What's wrong with what you have so far?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson in the chargepoints method I have hardcoded (.doc('WPHW9669')) instead of that I have to loop through the 145 collection and get the document first after that I have to go  inside that looped document to access the 'location' collection

Comment: Please edit the question to be more clear about what the problem is - don't just leave information in comments. There is an edit link at the bottom.

Comment: i have updated it @DougStevenson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer that I am looking for.

instead of creating a complicated collection, I change my collection to be simple.
new collection URL - 145/(Bus NO)/location/

```
    final result = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('145');
  busPoint() {
    result.get().then((snapshot) {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
        chargePoints(element.id.toString());
        print(element.id);
      });
    });
  }
```

the above method will loop through the '145' collection and call the chargePoints() method for each bus no's found(i registered the bus no as the document id).

```
  chargePoints(String element) {
    _db
        .collection('145')
        .doc(element) 
        .collection('location')
        .orderBy('updatedTime', descending: true)
        .limit(1)
        .get()
        .then((docs) {
      if (docs.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < docs.docs.length; i++) {
          LatLng position = LatLng(
              docs.docs[i].data()['position']['geopoint'].latitude,
              docs.docs[i].data()['position']['geopoint'].longitude);          
          initMarker(position, docs.docs[i].id);
          
        }
      }
    });
  }
```