# Accessing data from a sub collection in Firebase

Tags: android, database, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named 'room', inside which I've a document named 'users', inside the doc I've another collection named 'users' inside which I've filed named 'userName'. I want to access the 'userName'

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p27BX.jpg), [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvGXN.jpg), [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOynh.jpg)

Heres what I've tried

```
       StreamBuilder(
                    stream:  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(widget.roomId).doc("users").collection("users").snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, newSnapshot){
                      final documents = newSnapshot.data?.docs;
                      if (newSnapshot.connectionState ==  ConnectionState.waiting){
                        return Text("WAITING"); 
                      }
                     return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: documents?.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                            height: 25,
                            child: Text(documents![index]["usersName"] ?? "nothing found"),
                          ));
                    },
                  ),
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685504/5197712 Try this

Comment: Did u try this ans ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have misspelled the userName key in your text widget

```
child: Text(documents![index['usersName']??'Nothing found');
```

should be

```
child: Text(documents![index]['userName']??'Nothing found');
```